# GridView adapter, getView doesn't work

Tags: android, gridview, universal-image-loader, getview

I have custom adapter and i used Universal Image Loader library.

**MyFragment2**

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add("drawable://" + R.drawable.q);
mGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
mGridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter2(getActivity(), items));
```

**GridViewAdapter2**

```
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<String> mItems;

public GridViewAdapter2(Context context, ArrayList<String> items) {
    this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mItems = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SquareImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gridview, parent, false);
        imageView = (SquareImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    } else imageView = (SquareImageView) convertView;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(convertView.getContext()));
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .build();
    imageLoader.displayImage(mItems.get(position), imageView, options);
    return convertView;
}
...
```

What is wrong with my code? They compile but doesnt show any items. And doesn't call getView();

SquareImageView is simple square image view;

ty

Comment: post the whole adapter

Comment: "getView does not work" you say. My crystal ball I forgot. Explain better your problem you should...

Comment: Make a ViewHolder for item view

Answer (score 0):

1) Instantiating the `ImageLoader` and creating options doesn't belong into `getView()`, this should be done once, preferable inside the constructor.

2) From UIL's documentation for `drawable://`

> NOTE: Use drawable:// only if you really need it! Always consider the
>   native way to load drawables - ImageView.setImageResource(...) instead
>   of using of ImageLoader.

Are you sure you absolutely need to do so?

3) Take a look at how a `BaseAdapter` should be implemented (they work pretty much the same way for GridView and ListView), e.g. [this one](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.de/)

Answer (score 0):

@Xcihnegn ty, its work!

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    GridViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gridview, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new GridViewHolder();
        viewHolder.mImageView = (SquareImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else viewHolder = (GridViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(convertView.getContext()));
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .build();
    imageLoader.displayImage(mItems.get(position), viewHolder.mImageView, options);
    return convertView;
}

private static class GridViewHolder {

    public SquareImageView mImageView;
}
```